# Auto-add a bot to all channels on Slack?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am the admin of a Slack team.

Is there a way that I can auto-invite a bot to all slack channels that are created in my team?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible for public channels, but not for private channels.

You can subscribe to event types and use either the [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) or the [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) to make your bot listen to those events and react accordingly.

The event [channel_created](https://api.slack.com/events/channel_created) will be triggered each time a new public channel is created.

Unfortunately there is no pendant (e.g. group_created) for private channels (called "groups" in the API). I am guessing this is for security reasons. Private channels can only be accessed by a user or bot that is invited, so even `admins` and `owners` can not access private channels on their Slack team, which there have not been invited to.

Comment: The app will only be added to new channels created, how can you do this for preexisting channels?